# associated property in swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift2

I have written an extension in swift 2.0. I want to use associated property in my extension.

```
public typealias ShareCompletion = (result: AnyObject, error : NSError?) -> Void
private var ShareCompletionKey = "ShareCompletionKey"

extension UIViewController  {

var completionHandler : ShareCompletion? {
    get {
        return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &ShareCompletionKey)
    }
    set {
        objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &ShareCompletionKey, newValue, objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN)
    }
 }
}
```

Unable to identify the error in the code

Following are the errors:

`Cannot convert return expression of type 'AnyObject!' to return type 'ShareCompletion?'`

`enter code here Cannot convert value of type 'ShareCompletion?' to expected argument type 'AnyObject!'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is more trouble in your code, but most important is, that AnyObject is a protocol to which all classes implicitly conform. your ShareCompletion is not a class at all

```
import Foundation
public typealias ShareCompletion = (result: AnyObject, error : NSError?) -> Void
private var ShareCompletionKey = "ShareCompletionKey"

let sc: ShareCompletion = { result, error in }
print(sc.dynamicType) // (AnyObject, Optional<NSError>) -> ()
sc is AnyObject // FALSE !!!!!
```

Comment: So, there is no way we can use a closure variable in extensions because they are not objects? :(

Comment: you can use closure in extension, like you can use a function. you are not able assign the function or closure to the class, because they don't conform to AnyObject protocol.